# R - Automatic Creation of Data Packages

Tags: r

I have data on a server in the form of SAS data sets that are updated daily.  I would like these to be packaged auto-magically into R packages and then dropped in a package repository on the server.  This should allow my co-workers and I to easily work with this packaged data in R and keep up-to-date as it changes each day by simply calling `install.packages` and `update.packages`.

*What is a good way to implement this automatic creation of data packages?*

I have written some code that pulls in the data set, converts it and then uses `packages.skeleton()` to dynamically create the package structure.  I then have to overwrite the DESCRIPTION file to update the version along with some other edits.  Then finally have to call tools::build and tools::check to package the whole lot and drop it in the repository.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create an R file under your `data` folder to load data:

```
data
  --sas_data.R
```

And in this `sas_data.R` you write your code to load the data from the server. The code should be something like :

```
download.file(urll,dest_file)
## process here 
sas_data = read.table(dest_file)
```

Then you call it using `data`:

```
data(sas_data)
```

Comment: Does this mean that the data is not downloaded and converted until the user attempts to use it?  I was thinking that I would convert the SAS data sets as part of the package build process.  But this is definitely another way to go. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking that ideally there would be a "package build hook" (not unlike the package load hook) so that I could grab, convert and clean the SAS data set when the package is being built.

Comment: @NickAllen my idea is to prepare the data for the package. Imagine you have another source (some data base for example) you just add a new file  data_source.R in your data folder. Personally I have never use  this in production, but find the workflow robust.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `makefile` to automate the conversion of datasets. This would be useful especially if there are multiple datasets and the conversion process is time consuming.
I am assuming that the sas files are in a directory called `sas`. Here is the `makefile`.

By typing `make data`, all the `*.sas7bdat` files are read from the `sas` directory, using the package `sas7bdat` and saved as `*.rda` files of the same name in the `data` directory of the package. You can add more automation by adding package installation to the `makefile` and using a continuous integration system like `TravisCI` so that your R package is always up-to-date.

I have created a [sample repo](https://github.com/ramnathv/RDataPkg) to illustrate my idea. This is an interesting question and I think it makes sense to develop a simple, flexible and robust approach to data packing.

```
SAS_FILES = $(wildcard sas/*.sas7bdat)
RDA_FILES = $(patsubst sas/%.sas7bdat, data/%.rda, $(SAS_FILES))


data: $(RDA_FILES)

data/%.rda: sas/%.sas7bdat
    Rscript -e "library(sas7bdat); library(tools); fname = file_path_sans_ext(basename('$<')); assign(fname, read.sas7bdat('$<')); save($(basename $(notdir $<)), file = '$@')"
```

Comment: You can use this makefile in conjunction with this one [here](https://gist.github.com/halpo/1374344) to automate the entire conversion and build process. Deployment automation requires more info on your context.